# Android, catch singletap event on a child of ViewGroup but doubletap on the parent

Tags: android, events

I have a zoomable ViewGroup with some childs.
User can single-tap the child to select it but can also double-tap the ViewGroup to zoom/un-zoom the canvas.

The problem is if a child handle the `onTouchEvent` then the parent can't detect double tap. There is a workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the `onTouchEvent` method "Return true if you have consumed the event, false if you haven't."

I see 2 solutions for this issue:

1. Handle the double tap on the child view and notify the parent view about the action double tap through a listener
2. Handle the single tap on the child view but do not return true in the `onTouchEvent` method, because that way the parent will be also notified, and you can handle the double tap on the parent level.

Comment: Thanks, my current solution is to handle the parent event in the `onInterceptTouchEvent` so i can handle all gestures here and handle the single-tap event of the child using `onSingleTapConfirmed`. It seems a bit 'a trick but it works.